# rank($A$)=rank($B^{-1}A$)

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a matrix of dimension $n\times m$ and $B$ is nonsingular of dimension $n\times n$. It is easy to prove that rank($A$)=rank($B^{-1}A$) if $A$ is full rank. But, is the statement true in general, i.e., when rank($A$) $=r\leq m$?

Comment: What is your definition of rank? Do you know the correspondence between matrices and linear transformations?

Comment: rank(A) = # of linearly independent columns of A, i.e., the column rank of A. But, isn't the column rank and the row rank equal to the same number? Why is the term rank(A) ambiguous?

Comment: Yes, known simply as the rank.

Comment: @RCL it's just that there is a definition in terms of linear transformations that (in my opinion) makes this statement clearer, that's all :)

Comment: @GuidoA.Thanks for the comment, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the $j$-th column of a matrix $A$ is equal to the product $Ae_j$ with $e_j$ the $j$-th canonical vector. Hence, if the columns $i_1,  \dots, i_k$ of $A$ are linearly dependent, there exist sclars $a_1,\dots,a_k$ such that

$$
a_1Ae_{i_1} + \dots a_kAe_{i_k} = 0. \tag{1}
$$

Multiplying by $B$ to the right, one obtains

$$
a_1B^{-1}Ae_{i_1} + \dots a_kB^{-1}Ae_{i_k} = 0, \tag{2}
$$

and so *the same (number of) columns* are linearly dependent for $B^{-1}A$. Conversely, if  $B^{-1}A$ has some linearly dependent columns then we are in the situation of $(2)$, and right multiplying by $B$ we obtain $(1)$.

In particular, this shows that the minimum number $d$ of linearly dependent columns of $A$ and $B^{-1}A$ is the same, and this number determines the rank. If $d = 0$ then both have full rank, and if not, they have rank $d-1$ by the very definition of $d$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**  Let simply $M=B^{-1}$ which is nonsingular. Suppose that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=r$ and let $c_{1},\cdots,c_{n}$ the $n$ columns of $A$ and $c_{i_1},\cdots,c_{i_r}$ the $r$ linearly independent columns of $A$. Then the $Mc_1,\ldots,Mc_n$ are the $n$ columns of $MA$ and it's easy to see (using definition) that $Mc_{i_1},\ldots,Mc_{i_r}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: So there have to be exactly $r$ linearly independent vectors in $\{Mc_{1},…,Mc_{n} \}$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{rank}A$ is the dimension of the image of the linear map $f_A:K^m\longrightarrow K^n$ associated to $A$ and, as $B^{-1}$ is associated to an *automorphism* of $K^n$ since $B$ and $B^{-1}$ are non singular, it is also the dimension of the image of the composition $f_{B^{-1}}\circ f_A$, which is the linear map associated to the product $B^{-1}A$. So we have the chain of equalities
$$\operatorname{rank}A=\dim\operatorname{Im}f_A=\dim\operatorname{Im}f_{B^{-1}A}=\operatorname{rank}(B^{-1}A).$$

Comment: According to my definition, the product $AB^{-1}$ is not defined. I understand that in this proof you are saying that Im$f_A$=Im$f_{AB^{-1}}$, and as I see is a very simple statement to prove. But, I don't think that necessarily  Im$f_A$=Im$f_{B^{-1}A}$, which is what the problem asks.

Comment: @RCL: You're, I didn't check I was swapping $A$ and $B^{-1}$. It's fixed now; Thank ypu for pointing it! But why do you say the problem asks to prove the equality of images?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I understood that you were saying that the images are equal. Can you be more specific in the argument "the dimension of Im$f_A$ is equal to the dimension of Im$f_{B^{-1}A}$"? Is that a known fact given by the non-singularity of $B$?

Comment: It results from the fact that the associated linear map is an isomorphism, and as you know, isomorphisms do not change dimension.